# How to remove a duplicate Ubuntu Installation without ruining OS boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uninstall, bootloader

I have a dual boot setup:  windows vista and ubuntu.

But, I actually have a duplicate Ubuntu install that I setup a long time ago to get my bootmenu back... (my computer at one point could not find the boot record because I was playing around with the partitions.. i couldn't start the computer, had to install new UBUntu, and my boot menu came back).

So I want to get rid of this duplicate Ubuntu install without having the same problem again where I cannot get the boot menu.  The duplicate install is what caused my boot menu to appear again so thinking that they are connected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Know the partition on which the " / " directory of your primary Ubuntu is mounted**:

  Run this from your primary Ubuntu: `df`

  OR

  System > Administration > System Monitor > File Systems
- **Associate the GRUB (boot-menu) with your primary Ubuntu installation**:

  `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/dev/sdan /dev/sda`

  Replace sdan with the partition on which the " / " directory of your primary Ubuntu is mounted (sda1 or sda2 or sdan)
- **Remove the duplicate Ubuntu installation using a partitioning tool.**
- **Boot your primary Ubuntu, and run this command**:

  `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the duplicate and then run `sudo update-grub` in the remaining installation to update the grub menu. If you want to be safe, re-run `sudo install grub /dev/sda` where /dev/sda is the master boot hard drive. This will reinstall grub into the Master Boot Record, and configure it to point to your existing Ubuntu install's boot directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just do whatever you need to do to remove the extra Ubuntu installation (Like installing a new OS). Then just run the live version of Ubuntu (you can find it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)) and follow this guide that will show you how to restore grub: http://aroundtheweb.info/2010/10/restorerecover-grub-2-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7/