# To Remove Duplicates from two Ubuntu 11.04 installations

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, duplicate-files

I usually use Dual boot with WinXP and UBUNTU 11.04, but few days ago,one colleague made a mistake by installing again Ubuntu 11.04 on same partition where already it was present.

And Before that I had updated the Ubuntu 11.04,but in new installation,I had to do again, as Prompted by the system.

And In Grub Boot Loader,The list of OS shows following:
1.Ubuntu 
2.previous linux 
3.winXp.

So,  how can I clean up my ubuntu Disk space by removing Duplicates files  from New ubuntu installation ,caused by previous linux installation.

Comment: See this if it's help   http://askubuntu.com/questions/13052/how-to-remove-a-duplicate-ubuntu-installation-without-ruining-os-boot-menu

Answer (score 3):

Linux does not refer to Ubuntu. It refers to the kernel, which is a very small, but highly important part of Ubuntu. When you install a new kernel upgrade, the old one is not removed. The reason for this is that the kernel is a critical component, and if something goes wrong with it, you might not be able to boot and fix any problems. Considering the vast amount of different hardware out there, it is not impossible that something might break with a new kernel, and if it does, you will be able to simply choose "previous linux" and boot the Linux that didn't have any problems.

Linux itself doesn't use much diskspace, only a few megabytes, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Not all that well said, but this is correct. However, this doesn't fix their problem of duplicate files not related to this.

Comment: even I agree with new User,actually I need some tool to remove that duplicate linux,although it occupies whatever amount of space,but it creates confusion for new users to dual OS pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of unnecessarily files, you'll need to install from scratch. It's really the only way. The bootloader entry isn't actually an issue as jo-erlend describes.