# Remove Ubuntu 10.10 without affecting Ubuntu 12.04 in the same hard drive

Tags: 12.04, 10.10, partitioning, uninstall

I installed 10.10 to try the Macbuntu theme (evidently enough, it didn't work). I am trying to uninstall it, but I also have 12.04 on the same hard drive. How would I go about removing 10.10 without affecting 12.04? Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but generally, you'd just delete the partition the OS is on. The other OS should not be affected, if it is on a separate partition, but you may need to restore GRUB.

Comment: How might I go about deleting the partition in GRUB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use OS-Uninstaller**

**First thing first: *Make two copies of backup of all your data in external drives*.**

Step 1: Get OS-Uninstaller

**OS-Uninstaller must be run from a Live CD/DVD/USB.**

**1st option:** get a disk including OS-Uninstaller

Download [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd). Then burn the image on a CD, or create a [live-USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). Boot on it. A window (Boot-Repair) will appear, close it. Then launch OS-Uninstaller from the bottom-left menu.

**2nd option:** install OS-Uninstaller in Ubuntu

- boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- open a new Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
- Press Enter
- then type:

  sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
- Press Enter

**Launch OS-Uninstaller**

Then choose the OS you want to remove and click "OK"

[image: This is an image of OS-Uninstaller]

See [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) for details.

Also see [How to remove a duplicate Ubuntu Installation without ruining OS boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13052/how-to-remove-a-duplicate-ubuntu-installation-without-ruining-os-boot-menu) for another way of doing it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow!!! Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!